Error when Publishing Web API to the server
I have this error when I try to publish on the server the WEB API I have created:
Scripts/jquery-3.6.0.slim.js' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Scripts\jquery-3.6.0.slim.js'.  The semaphore timeout period has expired.
I tried to google but there's nothing I have seen to be clear or exactly the error I've got.
Has anyone encountered this kind of error and what solution did you do?
Thank you!
I tried to publish my work but not working.
